# Possible to upload documents to Watson discovery via Watson Assistant?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

I have been trying to find an answer to this question, but can't seem to have any luck.

Is it possible to upload a document to Watson Discovery via Watson Assistant?
If so, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you exactly mean, could you add more details? Watson Assistant could provide an upload link or help in some other means.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box that could do as you ask. Discovery does now come with a number of mechanisms to populate collections, i.e. Box, Web and sharepoint crawlers along with a manual upload. Non of these are integrated with Watson assistant. 
That's not to say what you are looking for cannot be done, but you would need to build the mechanism yourself. As an example you could create a response payload (json packet ) within Watson Assistant that triggers some client code which performs an upload. This upload could then directly push the document into a discovery collection via discovery's API methods.

Comment: in your opinion, would creating a response payload (json packet) within Watson Assistant to trigger some client code which performs the upload be something difficult to achieve/execute/create?

Comment: What client are you currently using to front your assistant?  - if its something you have written yourself i.e. a Javascript app then no, it would not be that difficult. I am sure if you search there will be examples of client applications that demo an upload process. This then just needs to be altered to then use the discovery api's. You could also use curl or postman to test out the discovery upload process and understand the required rest api that needs to be implemented.

Comment: As of this moment, I have only set up the watson assistant. I have been looking in discovery, but did not attempt anything as of yet. Do you by any chance have any client applications demo as a reference for me to look for?

Comment: Sorry I have nothing to hand, although I have seen similar demos in the past. I would just google upload and javascript.

Comment: Watson Assistant definitely does not accept a data stream in payload. Either you have to place the files in watson s3 service or host somewhere, pass the name of the file in watson assistant and write a cloud function to create a job to upload the document to discovery.